# CSS: Why I can't use ID in this piece of code but with class it works?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hi I have a weird issue here with my menu. So I want to apply this transformation to just few links and for other just to not have it.

Here is the CSS for the transformation without any changes:

```
ul.menu > li > a:after,
ul.drop-down > li > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  background: red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 }
```

Now this is applied to every a tag in the ul with class "menu". OK that's fine but I want to apply this only to some links. so If I put **ul.menu > li > a.foo:after** it will work but if I use id there **ul.menu > li > a#foo:after** it won't work. Any reason why so?

The problem is that if I stick with using the **class foo** instead of the ID than on the next pice of code trying to apply the class foo to the .active state doesn't work:

```
ul.menu li a:hover:after,
ul.menu li a.active:after {
  width: 100%;
 }
```

So here if I apply **ul.menu li a.foo:hover:after and ul.menu li a.foo.active:after** is not going to work. Any ideas why so?

Here is how my links look without putting th class foo to the

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a <?php if ($active_state == 'news'): ?> class="active" <?php endif; ?>           href="bla"><span>News</span></a></li>
    <li><a <?php if ($active_state == 'lounge'): ?> class="active" <?php endif; ?> href="blaa"><span>Lounge</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Post that exact code and markup you are using with your ID.  It works just fine.

Comment: BTW: As an ID has to be unique on a page, there is no need for selectors like `ul.menu > li > a#foo:after` - `#foo:after` will be sufficient (if it is not a matter of specifity). But as Axel already said, post your relevant HTML markup!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article contains information about the difference between ID and class. I believe because you'd have multiple `ul.menu > li > a#foo`'s this won't work with ID. ID applies to one element. 
http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: I manage to fix it by making the .active #active and make the foo .foo :)